# How to illustrate to students why they should use the standard library?

Tags: c++

Too often I run into students who:

- Use arrays instead of vectors, thinking that it's "faster"
- Use pointers because it's "faster"
- Reinvent-the-wheel, often copying-pasting terrible C-ish code from the Internet

They have this ingrained impression that before they write "correct" code, they have to write "fast" code, at the expense of learning. I know that gurus like Stroustrup and Meyers don't spend many hours and dollars writing books and speaking at conferences about the standard library only for it to be completely ignored because the student thinks they're better than the compiler.

I suspect the reason is:

- They're lazy. It's a lot easier to come up with crappy, C-ish code than it is to actually think about the problem and apply the appropriate tools
- They don't want to read books
- They think the standard library is slow
- It's fun reinventing-the-wheel; unfortunately they don't do a lot of research into understanding the problem or how to solve it properly

The problem, I believe, is that to students, reading and watching videos are boring, and they tend not to listen to those who say "use vectors instead of arrays" but have trouble articulating *why*. I struggle to find an alternative means of teaching the important concepts without being obtuse or boring.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Students have to reinvent the wheel, that's why they're students. Also, you're probably running into people who have prior programming knowledge and don't take what you say at face value.

Comment: This has to be the first question I've seen with a close vote over "asking for career or education advice" when it's an educator asking the question.  :-)

Comment: recommended reading: **[How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6630/31260)**

Comment: Having taught students in basic programming myself (In Java but with the same problems) I often encountered students clinging to Arrays even when container classes would be the better choice because they just didn't understand how to use them and what's the difference in using either arrays or containers. I highly discourage doc browns answer because imho those aren't "legacy" concepts but rather fundamentals of programming. It often helped giving them assignments with instructions to use "an apropriate container class" and "no arrays" to get them to learn how to use them and what they are.

Comment: @Aron_dc: in Java, arrays are surely no legacy concept. In C++, there is almost **no** good reason (only many false ones) which justifies to use an inbuilt array instead of a `std::vector` except the reason "because there is legacy code or a legacy API involved." The latter is true for pointers vs. iterators.

Comment: If they think pointers are faster, you could make an assignment to implement two programs with the same functionality - implement one with iterators, and implement the other version with pointers, and then as part of the assignment, run each one and produce benchmarks showing the runtime characteristics of each implementation.

Comment: Indeed.  This actually sparks my curiosity as to what the comparison would be.

Answer (score 8):

If you're a teacher: set them the appropriate assignment.

Write a program using stl vector to do something. Then set them another assignment to repeat the same task using C arrays. Get them to compare the performance of each. You should be able to demonstrate the insignificant difference in performance afterwards. Don't use collections of primitive types either, make sure its a complex type - a map of Students in a list of Classes using a vector of classrooms might be a good place to start explaining these things (as a map is for lookup of student ID - make it a string not a int that can be used as an array index - a list of classes that are dynamically changed, and fixed list of rooms.)

Then do the same for map and list and dequeue. The idea is not so much to teach them the difference of reusing the sTL containers, but to let them find out for themselves. Once they've implemented a linked list using C pointers, compared to the 1-line of code to do a stl list, they might start to get a clue.

The other aspect is to teach them when to use which kind of container. If you also set tasks that use unique_ptr and shared_ptr you could teach them how much faster and safer it is to use these compared to juggling object lifetimes with raw pointers.

Comment: Also be sure to point them to correctness and how fiddly it is, `new[]` requires `delete[]` and has overhead and malloc (heaven forbid) requires placement-new and explicit destruction of every element.

Comment: I think this is a great idea, get them to stress test a container class (such as Vector) for performance and correctness with millions of inserts, deletes, shuffles etc. This should take them a small number of hours if they know what they're doing. Part 2 of the assignment will be to repeat the process with your own implementation (evil grin:)

Comment: Hm, I feel that this approach would just run in circles. The whole idea is to get them *away* from writing C-ish code. There are C++ ways to write a linked-list. I can see the merit in showing them "bad code" in comparison to "good code", but even just showing them bad code might plant the seed in their heads.

Comment: Students need to know what is going on under the covers rather than just cargo-culting. Besides, your whole question was to stop them doing C code. One way to really get it into their heads is to show them the difference and that the STL is good, you can't do that by showing only one side of the argument.

Comment: This is a possible approach, of course. However, I would actually avoid teaching newbies two different concepts at once. And I think it is not so much important to let the students make a performance comparison - the more important thing to teach is that even if a container or datastructure is slower than the other, this does not matter in most cases  - not because the performance difference is neglectable, but because for real-world problems library containers are generally fast enough.

Answer (score 5):

Is it your job to rate your students or their code? Then it is easy: make clear what you expect from them and what kind of code you think is good, and when they present you solutions with good or bad code, give them the appropriate ratings. Be sure your students know to get past your course the goal is not writing the "fastest" code, but the most correct, most readable and most standard code.

And lead by example: when you present programming concepts or show example solutions, do not use C-style arrays or C-style pointers by yourself. Mention their existence only as a side-note, but tell your students clearly that those are language elements C++ inherited from C, for which the standard lib has better alternatives. Tell them they should learn these when they have to deal with legacy code, but not for passing the exams.

Answer (score 3):

It's all about incentive.

This doesn't count for each and every student but in general:
Your students are in school to get a diploma. Your class is one of many obstacles they need to overcome to get that diploma. They want to pass that class with the least amount of effort.

Now you're also working with smart individuals and when you post a problem (give an assignment) your students will not start looking for different ways to solve it if they already "think" they have the answer.

Why read the book if you think you already know how to solve the assignments?

Your job as a teacher is to provide enough "obstacle" that the diploma doesn't lose its value.

Answer (score 2):

In industry, we solve this problem by:

- Reviewing the code before it gets checked in.
- Marking code with such problems as defects.
- Not allowing it to be checked in until the author either fixes all the defects or successfully defends their design decisions as they stand.

Your colleagues over in English composition work the same way, going through multiple drafts.  Programming languages are just as difficult to write in as English.  I don't know why schools seem to think students can get it right on the first draft.